# Mail sender address is not getting updated in Debian

Tags: email, debian

I'm trying to send email, but I constantly get wrong sender email address.

From address supposed to be "**xyz@company.com**" but it is coming as "**xyz@guid**"

[image]

**OS details:**

[image]

The command tried so far:

> echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail" -r sender@company.com mail-to@receiver@company.com

> echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail" -r mail-from@sender@company.com mail-to@receiver@company.com

> echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail" -r 'First Last sender@company.com' receiver@company.com

> echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail" -aFrom:'First Last sender@company.com' receiver@company.com

> echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail"  receiver@company.com -aFrom:sender@company.com

> echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail"  -aFrom:IROL-Admin<sender@company.com> receiver@company.com

Comment: This question is not about programming. Unix and Linux Stack Exchange (one of our sister site, see link on top right icon) may be more relevant. Check your mailserver configuration. And you should add in the question which `mail` command are you using (usually it depends on which smtp [mail server] you have installed)

Comment: what software are you using to send email.
There is a software named Thunderbird Email. Did you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the below SSMTP.Conf

```
root=sender@company.com
mailhub=mailhost.company.com:25
FromLineOverride=YES
```